# Receive and send Facebook emails from an iPad

Tags: email, ipad, facebook

How do I log into Facebook email so that I can download and send from an iPad? I want to be able to receive and send using my Facebook account.

If my Facebook email address is example@facebook.com what are the credentials and settings I need to use to connect to Facebook mail servers?

I think I need the:

- incoming and outgoing server host names
- IMAP or POP
- login username

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977267/facebook-messages-access-via-imap the facebook servers don't support POP or IMAP since they weren't designed to be used by outside clients.